# Can I manipulate data to be saved in beforeRemote method in loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopback

I am trying to use beforeRemote("create", fn). I need to change a few fields before I continue to save the data I recieve.

I've tried to manipulate the data in the ctx.args, but with no luck. The saved data does not include the changes I've made.

I am using loopback 3.23.x, along with mongodb database. Can some one tell me what to do to manipulate data. Is this not what before remote is for?

```
  model.beforeRemote("create", async function(ctx, instance, next) {
    console.log(ctx.args)
    ctx.args = {
      ...ctx.args,
      tags: [ "one", "two" ],
    }
    console.log(ctx.args)
    return;
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `ctx.args` is containing all arguments. In your code snippet, you are setting the value for a named argument called `tags`. The built-in "create" method is not accepting any `tags` argument, that's why LoopBack (strong-remoting) is ignoring that extra data.

To modify the model data (property values), you need to change `ctx.data` object instead.

```
model.beforeRemote("create", async function(ctx, instance, next) {
  console.log(ctx.args)
  ctx.arg.data = {
    ...ctx.args.data,
    tags: [ "one", "two" ],
  }
  console.log(ctx.args)
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests : with mysql connector, the data to create are available in `ctx.req.body`.

You can modify it before data are saved into the database.

But it doesn't work with mongodb connector. 
With this connectors, the created values are available into `ctx.args.data` and you can modify them.

Hope it helps,